# Weird number of spaces at line-start. Are you using a 4-space indent?

Tags: c++, clang-format, cpplint

I use clang-format to get my C++ code into a Google-based style. And I use my modified-cpplint.py to check my format. Here's my format settings in Sublime Text 3:

```
{
    "BasedOnStyle"                  : "Google",
    "IndentWidth"                   : 4,
    "ColumnLimit"                   : 120,
    "AlignConsecutiveAssignments"   : true
}
```

After format my code turns into [this way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNwS3.png). And cpplint told me that "Weird number of spaces at line-start. Are you using a 4-space indent?" How can I fix it?

Comment: Does he complain for all statements that are broken on several lines or only for the conditional operator ?

Comment: Just this line. When a line is too long, it will break into several lines. Sometimes the number of spaces at line-start is a multiple of 4 so cpplint won't say anything. I can't figure out the rule.